# How to get the name of the service it is in order to log status on sql server

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I've written a windows service , and it calls a function then connects to a WCF client in order to send data from the computer to a sql server. How would I get the name of the service in the code in order to send it in a sql query. So in a function I want to get the name of the windows service that called the function.

```
Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

This is what I have now and I used it to get the application name when testing but i'm not sure if it works the same for a service.

Is this code right for a windows service or does it only work for a windows application. Because of tables dependencies in sql it is not working since service name is a primary key.

Comment: Should work. What value are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Well because it is a service, I dont have a way to test what value to get. In order for it to work I need to hard code it into sql table that my target table is having the service data inserted into. In the services window would it be the name column?

Comment: *"Well because it is a service, I dont have a way to test what value to get"*.  Sure you do.  Debugging Windows services is cumbersome but it's still possible and, even if you don't use the debugger, you could still add logging code to an installed service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a little confused in your project design. If the method that you write in windows service and the function used to invocate the WCF service is in the same project, why not you call the WCF service directly in Window service?
Besides, With reflection we can get the name of the corresponding assembly in any project, but if we want to call a function in Windows service based on its name, we are perfectly capable of calling the service directly provided that we have known the remote service address. Under this circumstance, we could generate the client proxy class to call the service method, just like we call the method in the local project.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.